# How to restart ng-repeat after data has been changed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My controller is

```
function calendarEventsController($scope) {
    var angUserEvents = [];

     // get data to array from json

    $scope.returnUserEvents = function(userDate){
     for (var i = 0; i <= angUserEvents.length-1; i++){
        if (angUserEvents[i].start == $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', userDate))
        {
            var dateToShow = angUserEvents[i];
            $scope.userEvents = dateToShow;
            //return;

        }   
     };
}; 

    $scope.userEvents = angUserEvents;
};
```

OK, it works good. Checking the scope of this controller, I see the list of objects `userEvents`, which is rendered by ng-repeat successfully.

```
<ul>
             <li ng-repeat="userEvent in userEvents">
                    {{userEvent}} 

             </li>
    </ul>
```

After this I manipulate this list in controller by `$scope.returnUserEvents`, selecting the one of object in it. To be sure that data is OK, I'm checking the scope of controller again, and I see that length `userEvents`has been changed - that's what I need.

After this, I assume that ng-repeat must be rerender (becouse of `$scope.userEvents` has been changed), however it is not so.

Comment: how did you call your $scope.returnUserEvents function?

Comment: Where is `returnUserEvents` called?

Comment: scope = angular.element("#angularList").scope();
scope.returnUserEvents(date);  

it calls in JS in one of event listeners.

Comment: and how did you run this code? :) from a dom event?

Comment: you right, from callback.

Comment: ok there is the problem: put your $scope.userEvents = dateToShow; in a $apply block: $scope.$apply(function(){$scope.userEvents = dateToShow;})

Comment: Trying to do like this:

$scope.$apply(function() {
returnUserEvents(date);
               });

however I'm getting the error: ReferenceError: returnUserEvents is not defined, however I see in $scope:

$get.g.$new.a {$id: "003", this: $get.g.$new.a, $$listeners: Object, $parent: g, $$childTail: $get.g.$new.a…}
$$childHead: $get.g.$new.a
$$childTail: $get.g.$new.a
$$listeners: Object
$$nextSibling: null
$$prevSibling: null
$$watchers: Array[1]
$id: "003"
$parent: g
returnUserEvents: function (userDate){
this: $get.g.$new.a
userEvents: Array[4]
__proto__: g

Comment: you should write $scope.$apply(function(){$scope.userEvents = dateToShow;}) with in your returnUserEvents function...

Comment: I mean that in $scope I see my method of controller, however I'm getting the mistake returnUserEvents is not defined

Comment: yes, you right! It was very useful for me. Thanks!if you would to right your comment as answer I will vote foк it.

Answer (score 3):

if you updated userEvents outside of a $digest cycle, you need to call

```
scope.$apply()
```

Comment: You right, however advice of Michael from comments was earlier. Thanks.